# Unable to see output of Swing program

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am using Ubuntu and when running basic Swing program the output is not perfectly visible.  The output could not see the components like label or button.The code is

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Swing1 extends JFrame
{

   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   JFrame jr=new JFrame("Hello World!");

JLabel l=new JLabel("FirstOne");

    JButton b=new JButton("End");
  // l.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

   jr.add(l);

   jr.add(b);

   jr.setVisible(true);

   jr.setSize(800,300);

   jr.setLayout(null); 

    jr.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
   }
}
```

I am getting output screen but label not displayed nor button my os is ubuntu.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Show some code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: you add some code here.

Comment: `jr.setLayout(null); ` That is part of the problem.  Remove it (replace it with `jr.pack()`) and get used to working with layouts.

Comment: Replacing jr.setLayout(null) with jr.pack() is working thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  :)  Another improvement might be along the lines of changing adding components to something like `jr.add(l, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

   jr.add(b, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `jr.setLayout(null)`, because that means you would have to use absolute positioning.

You can look at Java's available [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) to see which layout is appropriate for you.

You can use a [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow), like `jr.setLayout(new FlowLayout())`, and that way your label and button will be visible.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.awt.*; //So you can use the Layout Managers

public class Swing1 extends JFrame
{

   public static void main(String args[])
   {

    JFrame jr=new JFrame("Hello World!");

    JLabel l=new JLabel("FirstOne");

    JButton b=new JButton("End");

    jr.add(l);

    jr.add(b);

    jr.setVisible(true);

    jr.setSize(800,300);

    jr.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    jr.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }
}
```